# Setting "JAVA_OPTS" globally on Windows

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

I need to set -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 globally on Windows machine.
I tried to set JAVA_OPTS environment variable in `My Computer -> Properties ->Environment Variables` and also via `Control Panel->Java->Java Runtime Environment Settings` but these had no effect.
How can I set JAVA_OPTS (and specially `file.encoding` property) globally in windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did you try setting up environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` ?

Set this to `"-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"` and it is supposed to be picked up by jvm. But if it doesn't, you are left with no choice other than to use command line parameter.

Comment: `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` Worked. Thanks