# java.net.SocketException: A system call received a parameter that is not valid

Tags: java, exception

This exception shows in server logs when any I/O operation is performed.
I searched but could not get the reason of its occurence.
this is not affecting the code flow .

logs :
    'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1403635070779>

> ```
> ####<Jun 25, 2014 12:07:50 AM IST> <Error> <Socket> <somemail.com> <AdminServer>     <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS    Kernel>> <> <> <1403635070803> <BEA-000403> <IOException occurred on socket:     Socket[addr=/ip,port=61142,localport=7001]
>  java.net.SocketException: A system call received a parameter that is not valid..
>  java.net.SocketException: A system call received a parameter that is not valid.
>  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
>  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:163)
>  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:133)
>  at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readFromSocket(SocketMuxer.java:986)
>  at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocketOnce(SocketMuxer.java:920)
>  at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocket(SocketMuxer.java:887)
>  at weblogic.socket.JavaSocketMuxer.processSockets(JavaSocketMuxer.java:343)
>  at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
>  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
>  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
> ```

Comment: Can you provide more information.  If it is acceptable, can you paste the stack trace?

Comment: i have provided the server logs

Comment: Check if this helps---http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216713/java-net-socketexception-invalid-argument-connect

Comment: Can you paste some part of code that might be causing this?

Comment: actually code is not being affected and it shows this exception on performing any I/O operation.

Comment: Including file I/O? If so please post a stack trace of that. But you should be taking this up with the vendor.