# java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: create while running ant build

Tags: ant, weblogic, atg

I am getting error while running ant build and deploying ear file to web logic server. Compilation part is completed and in the end while it is creating and deploying the ear file to weblogic server, it is giving the error.

Earlier the Weblogic and ATG setup was in C drive but after moving to some other drive say H drive , I am started getting this issue.

Please provide some pointers regarding the same.

JDK Version - 1.6

Error :

```
[assemble-jar] java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: create
[assemble-jar]  at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:395)
[assemble-jar]  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
[assemble-jar]  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:476)
[assemble-jar]  at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
[assemble-jar]  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:424)
[assemble-jar]  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:538)
[assemble-jar]  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:214)
[assemble-jar]  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
[assemble-jar]  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:319)
```

Comment: Which version of ATG, Weblogic and ant are you using? Java 1.6 suggests an old version. The old assembler scripts required access to `java.sun.com`. After moving your code, do you still have access to the internet?

Comment: You might be encountering this bug relating to mapped drives on certain versions of windows  --> http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=2ffa5821d0e6706e45100be5b9b31?bug_id=6427062 and also here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216713/java-net-socketexception-invalid-argument-connect. Also please can you post the exact version of Java including any minor versions

Comment: ATG - ATG9.3, ANT - 1.7.1, JDK - jdk1.6.0_141, Weblogic - 11g