# Unable to connect to gRPC server when build as jar

Tags: java, sockets, grpc, java-11

I am trying gRPC and I having some issues. I have build a gRPC server and a client. Did almost the same as the java example of gRPC (https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/basics/) so nothing special. Now when I create a jar of the server it runs well but when I create a jar of my client it throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:271)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:252)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:165)
at com.example.grpc.server.classifier.classifierGrpc$classifierBlockingStub.classify(classifierGrpc.java:210)
at com.example.grpc.client.Main.sendMessage(Main.java:35)
at com.example.grpc.client.Main.main(Main.java:29)
Caused by: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: connect(..) failed: Invalid argument: /172.16.3.14:530
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connect(..) failed: Invalid argument
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newConnectException0(Errors.java:155)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.handleConnectErrno(Errors.java:128)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.connect(Socket.java:313)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doConnect0(AbstractEpollChannel.java:773)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel.doConnect0(EpollSocketChannel.java:144)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:758)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.connect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:600)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1342)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:548)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:533)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:54)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler.connect(WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler.java:157)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:548)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1000(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:61)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$9.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:538)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:394)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:995)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

This does not happen when I run the client in Intellij.

After searching for a while I found some posts that suggest using flag `java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to force ipv4 usage but that did not work.

Some versions of protobuf & gRPC

```
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.21.5'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.49.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.49.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.49.0'
```

So to be clear, the client works when it is run in Intellij but not when build as a jar.

Comment: Please take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73170621/14321268

Comment: Thanks, the answer on that post also solved it for me!

Answer (score 1):

For those using maven shade plugin:

```
<configuration>
    <transformers>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
    </transformers>
<configuration>
```

Reference to fix: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/9387